# Eigen Range Initialization

Tags: c++11, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to use Eigen3 to generate a 2d float matrix `(num_samples, num_ranges)` such that each column is a continuously spaced range from `[0, num_samples)` like `[0, 1, 2 ... num_samples - 1]`.

I'm currently achieving this by creating a similar 2d `std::vector` with `std::iota` and then converting that to an Eigen 2d matrix.

Is there a faster and simpler way to do this in Eigen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the matrix to be like

> 0 0 0 0
>     1 1 1 1
>     2 2 2 2
>     3 3 3 3

for a 4x4 matrix. For that, you can use a combination of `LinSpaced` (for a single column) and replicate (to duplicate that column):

```
int rows = 5;
int cols = 4;
Eigen::MatrixXd m = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(rows, 0.0, rows - 1).replicate(1, cols);
std::cout << m;
```